# Concerning subrings of a integral group ring

Tags: group-rings

Let $G$ be a group .

Does a subring of the integral group ring $\mathbb{Z}[G]$ has the form $\mathbb{Z}[H]$ for a subgroup $H$ of $G$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is $\mathbb{Z}[G]$ defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not necessarily.

Let $G=\{e,g\}$ have two elements. Consider, say
$$R=\{ae+bg:a,b\in\Bbb Z:a-b\in2\Bbb Z\}.$$

Comment: @ Lord Shark the Unknown Thank you for interesting answer. How about retracts of $\mathbb{Z}[G]$? i.e. if $S$ is a retract of $\mathbb{Z}[G]$, then is there a retract $H$ of $G$ so that $S=\mathbb{Z}[H]$?

Comment: @ Common If $G$ is a group and $R$ is any ring with an identity element, the group ring $RG$ is defined to be the set of all formal sums $\sum_{x\in G} r_x x$ where $r_x \in R$ and $r_x = 0$
with finitely many exceptions.

Comment: @ Common $RG$ is a ring together with the rules of addition and multiplication $(\sum_{x}r_x x)+(\sum_{x}r'_{x}x)=\sum_{x}(r_x +r'_x )x$ and $(\sum_x r_x x)(\sum_x r'_x x)=\sum_x (\sum_{yz=x}r_y r'_z )x$, respectively.